# Unable to import package com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

Need to implement MediaSessionConnector with exoplayer but i am unable to import package that is necessary for this. :

com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector

[image]

Below are my implementations added to app gradle(even added unnecessary ones like UI):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.10.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.10.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.10.8'
```

as per [document](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) this (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.8) should add all dependencies

whats missing here ? Any other implementations that is required for this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below package belonged to exoplayer:extension-mediasession -

> 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector'

Use below implementation to resolve the package dependency

`implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.10.8'`

got this from google official app gradle [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/io18/audio-app/build.gradle)